# How to fix the Could not determine whether the attribute type "System.Web.Services....."

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure Web Function in 4.8 framework that makes a bunch of web calls.  It has been running in the v1 azure functions but I am trying to move it to v4 which can run the 4.8 framework.

When I use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (4.0) it seems to compile correctly. (I having an issue with it not finding my function but that is another question).  But when I update to the 4.0.1 or more the build output is full of messages like the following:

Could not determine whether the attribute type

> 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute' used in the
> assembly 'eBay.Service.dll' derives from
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsStartupAttribute' because the
> assembly defining its base type could not be found. Exception message:
> Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> Could not determine whether the attribute type
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute' used in the
> assembly 'EntityFramework.dll' derives from
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsStartupAttribute' because the
> assembly defining its base type could not be found. Exception message:
> Failed to resolve assembly:
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' 17:34:41:139
>
> Could not determine whether the attribute type
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute' used in the
> assembly 'AWSSDK.Core.dll' derives from
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsStartupAttribute' because the
> assembly defining its base type could not be found. Exception message:
> Failed to resolve assembly:
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

These are all dll and not open source code.  EntityFramework is the one that seems the weirdest.  Also this locks Visual Studio and the only way out is by killing it in Task Manager.  Unable to cancel the build.

Comment: Could you provide what are the NuGet Packages you are using in .csproj file because you have to upgrade Function Code, NuGet Packages versions also supported for v4

Answer (score 1):

> I have Azure Web Function in 4.8 framework that makes a bunch of web calls. It has been running in the v1 azure functions but I am trying to move it to v4 which can run the 4.8 framework.

Whenever you are upgrading your functions, you should upgrade versions of all the Nuget packages of your application and Azure function version needs to be upgraded in project files and also have to modify the function code accordingly.

**V1:**
[image]
[image]

**V4:**

*Upgraded Azure function version to v4 and my Nuget package version to latest one in the project files.*
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

> Could not determine whether the attribute type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute' used in the assembly 'EntityFramework.dll' derives from 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.WebJobsStartupAttribute' because the assembly defining its base type could not be found.

And also I can see in that **messages you are getting**, it is referring that few assemblies could not found. So, I feel there must be issue with the packages you are using in your project. Try to update the versions of those packages or install if not installed.

Refer this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909021/how-to-fix-the-could-not-determine-whether-the-attribute-type-system-web-servic) and revalidate if you have migrated properly.